Django local server doesn't update web site with the new data from the database
CRUD operations are working just fine when I check the admins site. All of the new created items, updated or deleted are shown in the admins site, but in order to make the data appear in the website I have to restart my local server what's the problem
I'm working with python 3.11.9

Can you show your code in view ?
